# How to add providers for service

Tags: angular

For a component (@Component), I can use "providers: []" to add Injection token:

```
export const WINDOW_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<Window>('Window object');

@Component({
  providers: [
    { provide: WINDOW_TOKEN, useValue: window }
  ]
})
export class ExampleClass {
  constructor(@Inject(WINDOW_TOKEN) private windowObj: Window) {}
}
```

In this case, I don't have to create another service for this simple injection. Also, this `WINDOW_TOKEN` will be only load and use in `ExampleClass`. More important is, my test case can test `window.open()` by create a spy for `windowObj`

However, how can I do similar thing for a service (@Injectable)?

```
@Injectable({
  provideIn: 'root'
})
export class ExampleService {
  constructor() {}
}
```

So, for this code, how can I create a `@Inject` and only provide in this `ExampleService`, instead create another `@Injectable` and provide in root or module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only **register services in module-level or component-level**.

Taken from [Angular Docs: Providing Services](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#providing-services)

> You must **register at least one provider of any service you are going to use**. The provider can be part of the service's own metadata, making that service available everywhere, or you **can register providers with specific modules or components**. You register providers in the metadata of the service (in the @Injectable() decorator), or in the @NgModule() or @Component() metadata
>
> **When you register a provider with a specific NgModule, the same instance of a service is available to all components in that NgModule.** To register at this level, use the providers property of the @NgModule() decorator.
>
> **When you register a provider at the component level, you get a new instance of the service with each new instance of that component.** At the component level, register a service provider in the providers property of the @Component() metadata.

If you want to inject a service that is in the scope of another service, you should encapsulate both services in a same module.

E.g.

```js
@NgModule({
   declarations: [],
   imports: [],
   providers: [ServiceA, ServiceB]
})
export class MyModule{}
```

In your service, you can then inject the service that is only available in the same service scope.

```js
@Injectable({})
export class ServiceA{
  constructor(private sb: ServiceB) {}

  //Service methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class Service {
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply me Seba, but this is not what I want. Instead to creating a new service class and provide in root, I rather to use ```@Inject``` and provide in only the service.